# Parsing XML RPC result from Android

Tags: android, xml, xml-rpc

Do I need to place the XML result into a temporary local xml file and then parse from there? I'm trying to create a 'simple' currency conversion, using Foxrate's RPC API at http://foxrate.org/, and I'm stuck at trying to figure out what to do next. The XML examples that I've followed here are good, some are over the top for what I need (I think). I'm using the Android XML RPC library from code.google, so I can start with the below.

```
  uri = URI.create("http://foxrate.org/rpc/");
    client = new XMLRPCClient(uri);
    Object FoxResult = null;

    try {
        FoxResult = client.call("foxrate.currencyConvert", sourceCurrency, targetCurrency, conversionValue);
        Log.d("XMLRPC Test", "result conversion" );                 
    } catch (XMLRPCException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("XMLRPC Test", "Error", e);
    }
```

But then what? For the past couple days I've been trying to figure out how to pull the result struct apart and put them into variables I can use. Do I use DOM or SAX to pull out the information I need? And do I need to write an event Handler as mentioned here, http://www.anddev.org/web_services_-_an_xml-rpc_client_for_android-t646.html, for this? I've found that there's loads of information, but all with different solutions.

The response from the server is something like this:

```
   <params>
    <param>
        <value>

            <struct>

                <member>
                    <name>flerror</name>
                    <value>
                        <int>0</int>
                    </value>
                </member>

                <member>
                    <name>amount</name>
                    <value>
                        <double>50.36</double>
                    </value>
                </member>

                <member>
                    <name>message</name>
                    <value>
                        <string>"2/9/2007"</string>
                    </value>
                </member>

            </struct>
        </value>

    </param>
</params>
```

Thanks for any direction!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Map<String, Object> FoxResult = client.call("foxrate.currencyConvert", sourceCurrency, targetCurrency, conversionValue);
int flerror = Integer.valueOf(FoxResult.get("flerror").toString());
double amount = Double.valueOf(FoxResult.get("amount").toString());
String message = FoxResult.get("message").toString();
```

You'll need to do the appropriate checking for exceptions and missing values, but for `struct` types it returns a Map.

Comment: Much thanks, I will give it a try when I get back on my coding box!